# Javascript buttons and alerts not functioning properly. Alerts appear when page is refreshed but my buttons are not appearing

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on the beginning stages of js and trying to create buttons and alerts with it. when i write my code, the alerts work but my buttons are not appearing. when i inspect my webpage, the buttons dont even appear in the code. any suggestions on what i can do to fix this?

alertmessage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>alert message</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Javascript.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

code.js

```
 window.alert("Welcome to Javascript");
```

buttons.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>alert message</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Javascript.</p>
    <button onclick="alert('How can I help you?')">Click me.</button>
    <button id="button 2">Click me.</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementbyId("button 2").onclick=function(){
            alert("You have just clicked me!");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: alertmessage.html:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>alert message</title>
    </head>

    <body>
     <p>Javascript.</p>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js">
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>

code.js:
    window.alert("Welcome to Javascript");

Comment: buttons.html:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>alert message</title>
    </head>

    <body>
     <p>Javascript.</p>
     <button onclick="alert('How can I help you?')">Click me.</button>
     <button id="button 2">Click me.</button>
     <script>
      document.getElementbyId("button 2").onclick=function(){
       alert("You have just clicked me!");
      }
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: put the code in your post. not in a comment.

Comment: new to this website. how do i format for posting?

Comment: edit your question and put the code there

Comment: You have typo in `getElementbyId()` should be `getElementById()`.

Comment: Use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to enter HTML and JavaScript and make it executable.

Comment: stack snippet? not sure what that is.

Comment: @noah98 That's why I made it a link. Click on it and you'll find out.

Comment: You shouldn't have a space in an ID.

Comment: You have two HTML documents. If you view `alertmessage.html` you get the `Welcome to Javascript` alert. If you view `buttons.html` you get the buttons.

Comment: If you want both of them, you have to combine the two HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

well at first try not to use spaces when you create your buttons ids e.g (id="button 2")
instead use id="button2"
I modified your code adding the event listener on document ready find the below code hope that is what you are looking for, it should get your started.
Note: for posting here when you write your message paste your code under your message text and select the code then Press ctrl+K that should identify your code area then post it and all should work fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>alert message</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Javascript.</p>
    <button onclick="alert('How can I help you?')">Click me.</button>
    <button id="button2">Click me.</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(()=>{
            document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
                alert("You have just clicked me!");
            });

        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```